# Supporting Older iOS Version with MAUI

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, version, maui

We have been developing an application and I was using the latest VS with .NET 7 and the latest Xcode (14.1) The app works only with ios 16 or higher but does not work with the older versions like 14.2 or 15.5.

I downgraded the Xcode to 13.4.1 and downgraded VS to 17.3 (I added the version details end of the question)

But I have still Microsoft.ios 16.1.229 and I understand, it works as a workload but I could not downgrade it. I also use now .NET 6.0

Unfortunately I cannot even compile project. I get following warnings and errors.

```
/.../Platforms/iOS/Helpers/AppleDevicePermissions.cs(102,18): warning CA1416: This call site is
reachable on: 'iOS' 14.2 and later, 'maccatalyst' 14.2 and later.
'UIUserNotificationSettings.Types.get' is unsupported on: 'ios' 10.0 and 
 later, 'maccatalyst' 10.0 and later.
/...../Platforms/iOS/Helpers/AppleDevicePermissions.cs(102,18): warning CA1416: This call site is 
reachable on: 'iOS' 14.2 and later, 'maccatalyst' 14.2 and later
'UIApplication.CurrentUserNotificationSettings.get' is unsupported on: 'ios' 10.0 and later,'maccatalyst'
10.0 and later. [/..../MyApp.csproj]
ILLINK : warning MT0079: The recommended Xcode version for Microsoft.iOS 16.1.229 is Xcode 14.1 or later. 
The current Xcode version (found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer) is 13.4.1.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.1.229/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1007,3): 
error : Failed to AOT compile Microsoft.Maui.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1 [/../MyApp.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.1.229/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1007,3): 
error : Failed to AOT compile Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1 
[/....../MyApp.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.1.229/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1007,3):
error : Failed to AOT compile CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.dll, the AOT compiler exited with code 1 
[/...../MyApp.csproj]
```

[image]

```
  Visual Studio Professional 2022 for Mac
Version 17.3 (build 2102)
Installation UUID: 29d662e6-697b-4c96-a0cc-d9c2773c0a95

Runtime
.NET 6.0.5 (64-bit)
Architecture: X64

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.3.0-3.22312.2+52adfb8b2dc71ed4278debcf13960f2116868608

NuGet
Version: 6.2.1.2

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    6.0.400
    3.1.422
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    6.0.8
    3.1.28

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.19
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.0.0.0 (Visual Studio Professional)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-3/030cd63
Android SDK: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        12.0 (API level 31)
        11.0 (API level 30)
        13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.0

Build Information: 
Mono: dffa5ab
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d17-3@7716ae53
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.38.5@df4deab
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@14076a6

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.12
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.3.0.23
Hash: 965bf40
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-08-03 21:18:42 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1169
Hash: fafb1d5
Branch: fafb1d5
Build date: 2022-08-03 21:18:42 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504)
Build 13F100

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 8.12.0.2 (Visual Studio Professional)
Hash: 87f98a75e
Branch: d17-3
Build date: 2022-07-25 20:18:54-0400

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.12.0.2 (Visual Studio Professional)
Hash: 87f98a75e
Branch: d17-3
Build date: 2022-07-25 20:18:55-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.3.0.208
Hash: 0de472ea0
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-3
Build date: 2022-08-03 21:18:36 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1703002102
Git revision: 7a27f71b7aeb9b846940c9f8994c9ef7a694f0c2
Build date: 2022-08-03 21:16:13+00
Build branch: release-17.3
Build lane: release-17.3

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.6.0
Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0
    Mon Aug 22 20:17:10 PDT 2022
    root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

**UPDATE:**
I updated VS and Xcode to the latest version and I got this error

/...../MyApp/Platforms/iOS/Info.plist: Error: The MinimumOSVersion value in the Info.plist (11) does not match the SupportedOSPlatformVersion value (16.1) in the project file (if there is no SupportedOSPlatformVersion value in the project file, then a default value has been assumed). Either change the value in the Info.plist to match the SupportedOSPlatformVersion value, or remove the value in the Info.plist (and add a SupportedOSPlatformVersion value to the project file if it doesn't already exist). (MyAppApp) –

here is the related setting in thing info.plist

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the idea of downgrading? How did you conclude, that only IOS 16 is supported?!

Comment: Because our project manager said that some employee have old iphones and the app did not work on their phone.

Comment: @H.A.H. you mean, it would work? In the info.plist I made minimum system Version as 14.2, I got an error and could not build with this configuration.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-7.0 This is the official information what is supported and what not. If anything is off the list, this means it is not your MAUI framework to blame, but something else. I do not know what your problem is, I know its not the platform itself.

Comment: I have just made test app, Minimum Target IOS Framework 11.0. Builds without problem. This is like... 5 years old phones? At least...

Comment: @H.A.H. thank you so much. I actually opened this webpage and I was thinking why It did not work at me. But thank you for your leading, I'll then update everything and will try.

Comment: @H.A.H. I have now chance to try it but unfortunately I got the same error as I had.

Comment: /...../MyApp/Platforms/iOS/Info.plist: Error: The MinimumOSVersion value in the Info.plist (11) does not match the SupportedOSPlatformVersion value (16.1) in the project file (if there is no SupportedOSPlatformVersion value in the project file, then a default value has been assumed). Either change the value in the Info.plist to match the SupportedOSPlatformVersion value, or remove the value in the Info.plist (and add a SupportedOSPlatformVersion value to the project file if it doesn't already exist). (MyAppApp)

Comment: @H.A.H. I updated the questions as well

Comment: Do you have a line in your project file (not your info.plist) that specify the SupportedOSPlatformVersion, when you are building for IOS? It looks something like this: <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

Comment: It is complaining about mismatch between the two places where you define it. Set it in your project file, and build.

Comment: @H.A.H. I deleted SupportedOsPlatformVersion but I got the same error. I have some configurations as follow  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
  <CodesignProvision>Automatic</CodesignProvision>
  <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
  <EnableCodeSigning>False</EnableCodeSigning>
  <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
  <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
  <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
 </PropertyGroup>

Comment: @H.A.H. I took a SS https://prnt.sc/0TpBFZWtipdE

Comment: No no. Do not delete it. The project file is the most important place. You may or may not have it in the .plist. But in the project file you need to have it set correctly. You need SupportedOSPlatformVersion set, with condition that you build for IOS platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251434/discussion-between-ertan2002-and-h-a-h).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Thanks to @H.A.H and his idea. I downgraded all versions but the problem was not the versions.

As he shared a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-7.0

maui supports ios 11 and higher

So I updated my VS and Xcode to the latest version.

Then I created a complete new maui APP and open its csproj file and compared it with mine. I deleted unnecessary tags from my csproje file and then voilà! I could compile the project and deploy it to an old iphone.